# Drawing of Yggdrasil

Tags: story-identification

Roughly two decades ago I read a piece of juvenile fiction that had an incredibly intricate drawing of Yggdrasil in the first few pages. I thought it was *Choose Your Own Adventure #55* (*The Trumpet of Terror* by Deborah Lerme Goodman) so I purchased it from Amazon and was disappointed to see that that was not the one. So, anyone know of a piece of juvenile fiction about Norse mythology that has an intricate black-and-white line drawing of Yggdrassil (from Veðrfölnir at the top all the way down to Níðhöggr at the bottom)?

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps the following listing might help.  This was done via a search of Worldcat for all Juvenile Fiction containing Norse Mythology over the last 40 years.  If you use Amazon/Wiki to search for the title, you might recognize a cover/description.

E.g. for the first one below "Myth of the Norsemen", the chapter listing is below.  It has **Yggdrasill** as the first chapter.

**Yggdrasill the World Tree** -- Odin in search of wisdom -- The apples of Iduna -- Loki and the giants -- Loki makes mischief -- Freya the bride -- Thor's visit to Utgard -- Odin goes wandering -- Geirrodur the Troll King -- The curse of Andvari's ring -- Ægir's brewing kettle -- The death of Baldur -- Vali the avenger -- The punishment of Loki -- Ragnarok.

Cover pictures are at:

[http://www.amazon.com/Myths-Norsemen-Retold-Puffin-Classics/dp/0140367381](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0140367381)
[http://www.amazon.com/Myths-The-Norsemen-Puffin-Classics/dp/014134525X](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/014134525X)

Hope this helps.  Good luck.

==============

1. Myths of the Norsemen : retold from the Old Norse poems and tales / 
   Author: Green, Roger Lancelyn.; Langford, Alan, 
   Publication: London ; New York : Puffin Books, 1994, 1960
2. Norse stories / 
   Author: Hull, Robert, 1935-; Stower, Adam,; Heap, Jonathon, 
   Publication: New York : Thomson Learning, 1993
3. Eirksdottir. 
   Author: Clark, Joan. 
   Publication: Toronto : Macmillan Canada, 1993
4. Voyages : a novel / 
   Author: Smith, Doris Buchanan. 
   Publication: New York : Puffin Books, 1991, ©1989

   5.An introduction to Viking mythology / 
   Author: Grant, John, 1949- 
   Publication: London : Grange Books, 1990

   6.Voyages : a novel / 
   Author: Smith, Doris Buchanan. 
   Publication: New York, N.Y., U.S.A. : Viking, 1989

   7.Axe-age, wolf-age : a selection from the Norse myths / 
   Author: Crossley-Holland, Kevin. 
   Publication: London : Faber, 1988, 1985
   Document: English : Book : Fiction : Juvenile audience

   8.Iduna and the magic apples. 
   Author: Mayer, Marianna.; Gal, Laszlo, 
   Publication: Macmillan, 1988

   9.Usborne illustrated guide to Norse myths and legends / 
   Author: Evans, Cheryl.; Millard, Anne.; Matthews, Rodney, 
   Publication: Tulsa, Okla. : EDC Pub., 1987

   10.The curse of the ring / 
   Author: Harrison, Michael, 1939-; Humphries, Tudor. 
   Publication: Oxford : Oxford University Press, 1986
5. Stories of the Norsemen / 
   Author: Boucher, Alan, 1918-; Péron, Réne. 
   Publication: London : Burke, 1983
6. Balder and the mistletoe : a story for the winter holidays / 
   Author: Barth, Edna.; Cuffari, Richard, 
   Publication: New York : Seabury Press, 1979
7. The heroes of Asgard : tales from Scandinavian mythology / 
   Author: Keary, Annie, 1825-1879.; Keary, Eliza,; Brock, C. E. 
   Publication: London, Eng. : Macmillan, 1979
8. Balder and the mistletoe : a story for the winter holidays / 
   Author: Barth, Edna.; Cuffari, Richard, 
   Publication: New York : Houghton Mifflin, 1979
   Document: English : Book : Fiction : Juvenile audience
9. The heroes of Asgard : tales from Scandinavian mythology / 
   Author: Keary, Annie, 1825-1879.; Keary, Eliza,; Brock, C. E. 
   Publication: Great Neck, N.Y. : Core Collection Books, 1976, 1870
10. Baldur and the mistletoe; a myth of the Vikings, 
    Author: Hodges, Margaret, 1911-2005.; Hoover, Gerry, 
    Publication: Boston, Little, Brown 1973, ©1974
11. A comparative anthology of children's literature. 
    Author: Nelson, Mary Ann, comp. 
    Publication: New York, Holt, Rinehart and Winston 1972
12. Lord of the chained / 
    Author: Carter, George Goldsmith. 
    Publication: New York : Lothrop, Lee & Shepard, 1972
13. The heroes of Asgard : tales from Scandinavian mythology / 
    Author: Keary, Annie, 1825-1879.; Keary, Eliza.; Brock, C. E. 
    Publication: London : Macmillan, 1972, 1930
14. Why Heimdall blew his horn; tales of the Norse gods. 
    Author: Laing, Frederick, 1905-; Dillon, Leo,; Dillon, Diane, 
    Publication: Morristown, N.J., Silver Burdett Co. 1969